# PowerPivot trend lines

Tags: excel, charts, powerpivot

I would like to chart a trend line using Excel PowerPivot (data come from an Analysis Services cube). The data in the PivotTable should show the time horizontally (in my case I have weeks as column labels). I understand PowerPivot requires time variables to be vertical (as row labels).

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Power Pivot, the add-in for Excel data modeling and analysis tool, or are you using an Excel pivot table pointing at an Analysis Services cube?

Either way, time labels can easily be placed in the row labels or column labels section of the pivot table, and where you place it in a pivot table will determine what axis it goes on in a pivot chart. If you are unsatisfied with the default layouts, you can make a normal Excel chart which merely points to the cell range the pivot table occupies, and define any range to be the axis and any range to be the values.